# How to playback Lidar pointcloud from bag file in ros, rviz?

Tags: ros, lidar

I got a bag dataset and want to play the message containing velodyne VLP-16 points back. But got uncomplete result.

I've tried:
- increasing fps in rviz
- using timestamp from other simulation

I expect to got uncut result / a ring of lidar radius beam.

This is the result I got in rviz
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSyi5.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the points are available but they are not visible long enought because points are not showed simultaneously. The reason is that a single message does not contain all points of a complete (360°) beam. A beam gets splittet to several messages typically, of which only the latest gets shown by default. Checking the [rviz point cloud documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud) you will find a parameter called **decay time**:

> The amount of time to keep a cloud/scan around before removing it. A value of 0 means to only display the most recent data.

Try increasing the value of this parameter in rviz, then you should be able to see more points simultaneously.